# Did mumble-server package disappear in Ubuntu Server 18.04.1?

Tags: mumble

Recently I had mumble-server installed and working on Ubuntu server 18.04 (which was fully updated).  However, I just spun up another VM (18.04.1) via Virtualbox and after updating everything I cannot: apt-get install mumble-server
What am i missing or did it disappear?

I get the following:
Unable to locate package mumble-server

If i run it on my desktop Ubuntu 18.04.1 it proceeds like normal and will let me install it but I usually cancel because server doesnt even get this far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably missed to enable the **Universe** repository. It seems the server is still in the official repository, here the page :

> https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/mumble-server

If you don't know how enable to Universe repository, you can read the official guide.

> https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu

Comment: This is something I never had to do when installing mumble-server on my other Ubuntu server version.  Any idea why it would have changed where I need to manually do it now?  Like you I verified the first link but it only says 18.04, not 18.04.1 so I wondered if something changed.

Comment: Also, for Universe: "Canonical does not provide a guarantee of regular security updates for software in the universe component, but will provide these where they are made available by the community. Users should understand the risk inherent in using these packages."  I dont think i want to do that.

Comment: Checked older version, and seems this package was always in Universe.

Comment: Thanks for checking.  This is interesting because i dont change the way i install Ubuntu Server, its just default settings.  Apparently the desktop version and Server versions are seeing different things and maybe thats intended?  I'll try adding universe to server so I can get that package.  Thanks